# Unique and Mandatory Email-id while adding new lead in OpenERP7

Tags: odoo

I am new in OpenERP and have a task to achieve.

I want to keep Email-id **unique** and **mandatory** while adding new lead in CRM. I would like to know which is the best way to achieve it.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use _constraint for the field email address where it checks for the uniqueness of the field. use required=True for making it required for each data.

Cheers,
Parthiv